# Steam Api: How to get current game players?

Tags: steam, steamworks-api

Im trying to get the current players in a steam game with api. The player list that you can see in the steam overlay where "View Players" button is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the #GetPlayerSummaries docs.

Keep in mind that if the player in question has their profile set to "Friends Only" or "Private" YOU WILL NOT BE ABLE TO SEE IF THEY ARE IN-GAME OR NOT.

Here is the documentation:
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29

Here is an example URL you would want to hit with a `get` request:

```
 http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamids=76561197960435530
```